# generate dynamic rows in pdf using html2pdf

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf to generate a pdf.i need to generate some rows dynamically.
 My code is..

```
         <?php
        require_once("html2pdf.class.php");
        $content = '<html><body><table border="0"  >
        <tr><td align="center" > <h4><b> CHAMPIONSHIP
        2015-16</b> </h4></td> </tr>
        <tr><td align="center"><h4><b>
        </b></h4></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="center"><h4><b>DETAILED ENTRY</b>
        </h4> </td></tr>
        <tr><td><h4><b>Name of Manager :</tr>

        </table>
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF
        ('L','A4','de',true,'UTF-8',array(10, 10, 10, 10));
        $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
        $html2pdf->Output($filename.'.pdf');
```

How i can add php inside this content.If it doesn't work anyway pls suggest something else to generate the pdf..Thank you

Comment: can you give sample dynamic rows you want to add?

Comment: I need to fetch values from the db.$List = mysql_query("somequery");
     while($element= mysql_fetch_array($List))
        {
        //add rows according to result
        }

Comment: how can i integrate this code to $content

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do this like basic PHP ?

```
$your_var = 'what you want';

$content = '<html><body><table border="0">';
$content .= '<html code...>'.$your_var.'</...html code>';
$content .= '</table></body><html>';
```

Comment: adding variable is ok..but i need to use it like $content =' ..<table> <tr><td>if(something){ echo " something"}</td><tr></table> OR <table> while(condition){ //generate rows here }</table>

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 <?php
    require_once("html2pdf.class.php");
    $content = '<html><body><table border="0"  >';
    db.$List = mysql_query("somequery"); 
    while($element= mysql_fetch_array($List)) { 
    $content .= '<tr><td>'.$element["value"].'</td></tr>';
    }

    $content .= '</table></body></html>';
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF
    ('L','A4','de',true,'UTF-8',array(10, 10, 10, 10));
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output($filename.'.pdf');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just like this:

```
$content = '<html><body><table border="0">';
$content .= '<tr><td>';
if(your_condition){
    $content .= 'what you want';
}
$content .= '</td></tr>';
while(other_condition){
    // What you want in your loop (generate rows)
    $content .= '<tr><td>'.$line_number.'</td></tr>';
}
$content .= '</table></body><html>';
```

You can use ternary operator for conditions instead of if/else:

```
$content .= '<tr><td>'.(condition ? 'Some text' : 'other text').'</td></tr>';
```